# How can I view the website from the Maker Pro IoT Smoke Alarm?

Tags: security

https://maker.pro/arduino/projects/iot-smoke-alarm-arduino-esp8266-gas-sensor

I'm a layman who wants to do this. Have completed it as shown in the link.

But I don't know how to see the website and not make red LED glow instead of green when I bring a matchstick close to the sensor.

Comment: The project has missed explaining how to get the ESP8266 module to connect to a WiFi AP. Have a look at the AT command `AT+CWJAP` here https://www.electronicshub.org/esp8266-at-commands/

Comment: Using a matchstick is not the best way to trigger a smoke alarm even though it might work (you do not want to trigger a smoke alarm if you light a candle in the room - even if the distance is larger). There are dedicated smoke detector test sprays available that allow for more reproducible results.

Answer (score 3):

`esp8266_command("AT+CWMODE=2\r\n",1000,DEBUG);` line set the esp8266 as acces point which means it itself start a hotspot to whom you have to connect other device. You should replace 2 by 1 to act in station mode so that you can connect to router.

`esp8266_command("AT+CWJAP=”SSID”,”PASSWORD”\r\n",1000,DEBUG);` command which is missing can be used to connect to router.

`esp8266_command("AT+CIFSR\r\n",1000,DEBUG);` prints your current local **ip address**. This ip is what you want to open the hosted website. Copy the ip and paste on chrome on connected computer. **Remember the computer and esp must be connected to the same wifi network to work this.**